# run vnstat from a python script

Tags: python, command-line, interface, bandwidth, kvm

When running

```
vnstat -i [interface] --oneline
```

the selected interface's bandwidth usage is printed.

```
1;eth0;10/11/11;1.45 MiB;801 KiB;2.23 MiB;0.59 kbit/s;Oct '11;3.93 MiB;2.06 MiB;6.00 MiB;0.05 kbit/s;3.93 MiB;2.06 MiB;6.00 MiB
```

But to print all bandwidth usages from all interfaces, I need to run the following to get all the interfaces' name

```
vnstat --iflist
```

Then iterate through the result to store a usage result in a list

```
for item in result.split():
    # usage = run command 'vnstat --oneline -i [interface]
    # usageList.append(usage)
print ''.join(usageList)
```

The above script works but is running slow if there are many interfaces. How to optimize?

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that tons of awesome network stats are available in [/proc/net/*](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html) -- very fast
2. If you really want `vnstat` (which looks neat!), here's some code that scans each network interface in parallel.

   import multiprocessing, subprocess, time

   def check_net(iface):
       return (
           iface,
           subprocess.check_output(
               ['vnstat','--oneline','-i',iface]
           ),
       )

   ifaces = subprocess.check_output(
       ['vnstat', '--iflist']
       ).split()[2:]

   try:
       while True:
           pool = multiprocessing.Pool(len(ifaces))
           for iface,output in pool.imap_unordered(check_net, ifaces):
               print iface.upper(), 
               if 'Error' in output:
                   print '?'
               else:
                   print output.rstrip()
           print
           time.sleep(10)
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
       pass

### Output:

```
LXCBR0 1;lxcbr0;06/02/14;0 KiB;3 KiB;3 KiB;0.00 kbit/s;Jun '14;0 KiB;3 KiB;3 KiB;0.00 kbit/s;0 KiB;3 KiB;3 KiB
WLAN0 1;wlan0;06/02/14;7.77 MiB;401 KiB;8.17 MiB;1.11 kbit/s;Jun '14;7.77 MiB;401 KiB;8.17 MiB;0.46 kbit/s;7.77 MiB;401 KiB;8.17 MiB
ETH0  eth0: Not enough data available yet.
LO ?

ETH0  eth0: Not enough data available yet.
LXCBR0 1;lxcbr0;06/02/14;0 KiB;3 KiB;3 KiB;0.00 kbit/s;Jun '14;0 KiB;3 KiB;3 KiB;0.00 kbit/s;0 KiB;3 KiB;3 KiB
WLAN0 1;wlan0;06/02/14;7.77 MiB;401 KiB;8.17 MiB;1.11 kbit/s;Jun '14;7.77 MiB;401 KiB;8.17 MiB;0.46 kbit/s;7.77 MiB;401 KiB;8.17 MiB
LO ?
```